# AsphyreSphinx - how to desaturate image

Tags: delphi, directx, delphi-xe2, directx-9

I am using AsphyreSphinx framework to draw 2D DirectX scene on form canvas. Since their forums are closed, I have to ask here for help. I am drawing image to form canvas like this:

```
DXCore.Canvas.UseImage(TableResources.TableImage, TexFull4);
DXCore.Canvas.TexMap(FMetrics.RawTableBounds, clWhite4);
```

`TableResources.TableImage` is of `TAsphyreImage` type. `DXCore.Canvas` is `TAsphyreCanvas`.
This works fine and draws proper image. However, I have need to also draw black & white version of the same image (desaturate it).

I have tried to use various combinations of parameters in `TexMap()`, but none gave nothing close to desaturated image. Some things I tried:

```
DXCore.Canvas.TexMap(FMetrics.RawTableBounds, cGray4(100));
DXCore.Canvas.TexMap(FMetrics.RawTableBounds, cRGB4(100, 100, 100));
```

There is 4th parameter to function that takes `TBlendingEffect` enum, I tried various combinations with that too, but without success.

I also tried to manually desaturate image after loading it, with `cLerp()`, like this:

```
procedure TTableResources.ImageToGrayscale(const AImage: TAsphyreImage);
var
  C1: Integer;
  x, y: Integer;
begin
  for C1 := 0 to AImage.TextureCount - 1 do
    for x := 0 to AImage.Texture[C1].Width - 1 do
      for y := 0 to AImage.Texture[C1].Height - 1 do
        AImage.Texture[C1].Pixels[x, y] := cLerp(AImage.Texture[C1].Pixels[x, y], cColor(cGrayValue(AImage.Texture[C1].Pixels[x, y])), 0.8);
end;
```

..but this works awfuly slow (~20-30 seconds to process one image), and doesnt return desired output.

Here are some documents from their help:

[Asphyre.Types](http://asphyre.afterwarp.net/help/Asphyre.Types.html)

[Asphyre.Canvas](http://asphyre.afterwarp.net/help/Asphyre.Canvas.TAsphyreCanvas.html)

Does anyone know something more about this and can give me an hint or advice what I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asphyre Sphinx wasn't designed for processing images but for rendering them. It is a graphical engine suitable for making games.

Its original developer has ceased work on it. Currently it is maintained by a member of Pascal Game Development comunity named MarcoCestari. So if you have any questions related to Asphyre Sphinx you can join PGD comunity and ask there. These is a special forum section reserved for Asphyre Sphix library:

http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/forumdisplay.php?25-Asphyre-Component-Pack-(formerly-PowerDraw)

Now what you need would be some image processing library like Graphics32 for instance instead.

Comment: We have dedicated subforums for most graphical engines developed and used by pascal game developers. Main reason for this is to keep our forums well organized. Same also aplies to some other libraries aswel. And if anyone of you is interested in making games with Delphi/Objective Pascal feel free to join us. And if you wanna see how game engine is being made basically from scratch or even contribute in making of such game engine then by all means come and join us. We are curently in the process of creating our own comunity game engine ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, figured out how to desaturate it. This function will convert it to grayscale when called:

```
procedure DesaturateImage(const AImage: TAsphyreImage);
type
  PPixelRec = ^TPixelRec;
  TPixelRec = packed record
    B: Byte;
    G: Byte;
    R: Byte;
    A: Byte;
  end;
var
  C1, x, y: Integer;
  bitsp: pointer;
  pitch: Integer;
  bytes_per_pixel: Integer;
  pixel: PPixelRec;
  gray_value: Byte;
begin
  for C1 := 0 to AImage.TextureCount - 1 do
  begin
    AImage.Texture[C1].Lock(Rect(0, 0, AImage.Texture[C1].Width, AImage.Texture[C1].Height), bitsp, pitch);
    try
      bytes_per_pixel := pitch div AImage.Texture[C1].Width;
      for y := 0 to AImage.Texture[C1].Height - 1 do
        for x := 0 to AImage.Texture[C1].Width - 1 do
        begin
          pixel := PPixelRec(Integer(bitsp) + y * pitch + x * bytes_per_pixel);
          gray_value := Round(0.30 * pixel^.r + 0.59 * pixel^.g + 0.11 * pixel^.b);
          pixel^.r := gray_value;
          pixel^.g := gray_value;
          pixel^.b := gray_value;
        end;
    finally
      AImage.Texture[C1].Unlock;
    end;
  end;
end;
```